# Scala Futures and java 8 CompletableFuture

Tags: java, scala, akka, java-8

The introduction of `CompletableFutures` in Java 8 brought to the language features available in the `scala.concurrent.Future` such as monadic transformations.

- What are the differences, and why a Scala developer should prefer Scala Futures over java 8 `CompletableFuture` ?
- Are there still good reasons to use the `scala.concurrent.Future`in Java through `akka.dispatch` bridge?

Comment: imho, because monadic operations on CompletableFuture isn't defined coherently with monadic operations neither in Java 8 nor in Scala collections - so semantic isn't consistent. And also for me such semantic  seems too redundant. + You will have to deal with Java-Scala interoperability without any profit from that.

Comment: Can you please detail your comment with am answer? What about also the akka.dispatch bridge to use Scala futures in Java?

Comment: 1) I just mean that there is no `stream` method on CompletableFuture, so you can't just call map-reduce (and as a reult functions like filter) there as usual - have to use some ugly methods. also there is no for-comprehension for CompletableFuture of course. I didn't use CompleteFuture in practice (it's so ugly) - so can't answer your question completely 2) As I understand the topic is about java's futures in scala.

Comment: You are right about the for comprehension. I also added a second point, can you please provide your opinion?

Comment: there is some potential interoperabilty problems: akka.dispatch.Future requires scala's functions. There is an eperimental interoperabilty with Java 8 functions for Scala 2.11/2.12 - https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat, but you know it's experimental.

Comment: This blogpost might provide some context for Scala futures: http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/16/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-9-promises-and-futures-in-practice.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> What are the differences, and why a Scala developer should prefer Scala Futures over java 8 CompletableFuture ?

Rephrasing what @dk14 pointed out in comments I'd say that `CompletableFuture` doesn't have idiomatic Scala api.

For scala developer the implications  are:

- lack of for comprehensions due to fact that it does not follow Scala method conventions common for monadic types
- java-scala interop overhead needed when using big part of it's methods

It is also worth noting that java `CompletableFuture` is not exactly equivalent of scala `Future`. It is rather a fuse of scala `Future` and `Promise`.

Considering the cons listed above there isn't much sense in using `CompletableFuture` in scala unless you are designing public api that should be seamlessly interoperable with java.

> Are there still good reasons to use the scala.concurrent.Future in Java through akka.dispatch bridge?
>
> I am particularly looking for reasons to use akka.dispatch in Java, if there are still any

Akka is build on top of scala and it sometimes uses scala `Future`s. This means that in cases when you have some portion of code written in java it is worth to wrap it in scala api (with `akka.dispatch` java api) to be able to easily use it with akka.

For example, you are implementing akka actor in java. When processing message you want to do some non-blocking reading that, when done, should produce result as a message to another actor.

What you could do is to put your I/O into java [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html), then use [akka.dispatch.Futures#future](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/index.html#akka.dispatch.Futures$@future%5BT%5D%28body:java.util.concurrent.Callable%5BT%5D,executor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext%29:scala.concurrent.Future%5BT%5D) to get scala `Future` out of it, and then you could leverage akka [pipe](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/index.html#akka.pattern.package@pipe%5BT%5D%28future:scala.concurrent.Future%5BT%5D%29%28implicitexecutionContext:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext%29:PipeToSupport.this.PipeableFuture%5BT%5D) to make result of the future be delivered as a message to some actor.